# how to do i make it do the href text will be changable by c#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have the string list_name and I want the href link text to be the string inside `list_name` and not the word `list_name`. How do I do it?

```
 public void ShowButtonLists(DataTable table, int length)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                string list_name = table.Rows[i].ToString();
                Response.Write("<td> <a href='ShowList.aspx?listname=" + list_name + "'>list_name</a></td> ");
                Response.Write("<br/>");
            }
        }
```

Comment: just keep track of opening/closing quotes...  listname='" + list_name + "'>" + list_name + "</a>...

Comment: Also maybe consider taking advantage of string interpolation.  Quotes become less of an issue and it reads better while coding

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void ShowButtonLists(DataTable table, int length)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                string list_name = table.Rows[i].ToString();
                Response.Write("<td> <a href='ShowList.aspx?listname=" + list_name + "'>"+list_name +"</a></td> ");
                Response.Write("<br/>");
            }
        }
```